# Creating a domain based off specific attribute selection or lookup table in ArcGIS/Access?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, domains, personal-geodatabase, ms-access

Is it possible to have a domain on a database in ArcGIS that creates a drop down pick list on an attribute then have the next field have a domain based on that section?

For example:

- Field A - choose between cat, dog, cow, chicken, snake
- Field B - choose between white, black, red, brown ONLY IF I PICK 'CAT'
- Field B (may also) - choose between purple, yellow, blue ONLY IF I PICK 'DOG'
- FIELD C - stripes, spots (ONLY IF I PICK 'CAT' THEN 'WHITE'

and so on........

I do not want to create a script and run that   to update the attribute table in arc every time a selection of list of attributes is made.

Comment: This is worth a read over
https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/a-quick-revisit-subtypes-and-domains-in-collector-for-arcgis/

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  The tour states that there should be only one question per question, however in adding your "alternatively" question at the end you have made this too broad.  Please [edit] your Question to focus on one specific question, and you can ask your other question separately if required (although the answer to this one may render the second question unnecessary).

Comment: As far as I'm aware dynamic domains are not possible in out-of-the-box ArcGIS.  Third party tools may do it, although the only one I have seen that does is likely to be in the very very high price range (it's a small part of a much bigger product).

Comment: The subtypes would work, but I would need it to cascade down to multiple fields based on the choice of the first field... that is the issue. I'm not familiar with dynamic, but if they are not possible then never mind that

Comment: Since I couldn't figure out how to do this with domains, I made a custom addin that uses a hierarchical classification scheme to present users selections based on the previous selection. Take a look at it [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=aaa88d03d6cd499db77f663bdcb77173)